# How can I fix setState() so that it works?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm following Bob Ziroll's free scrimba course on React.

Thing is, my code is the same with his and it has been working so far...

but it isn't working anymore.

Here's my code

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import TodoItem from "./components/TodoItem";
import todosData from "./components/todosData";

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super()

    this.state = {
      todos: todosData
    }
    
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
  }

  handleChange(id) {
    this.setState(prevState => {
      console.log("PrevState Start ", prevState.todos )
      const updatedTodos = prevState.todos.map(todo => {
        if (todo.id === id) {
          todo.completed = !todo.completed
        }
        return todo
      })

      return {
        todos: updatedTodos
      }
    })

    console.log("Changed", id)
    
  }

  render() {
    const todoItem = this.state.todos.map(x => 
      <TodoItem handleChange = {this.handleChange}
        key={x.id} 
        item={x}
      />
    )

    return (
      <div>
        {todoItem}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

And here's the code for **TodoItem.js**

```
import React from 'react'

function TodoItem(props) {
    return (
        <div>
            <input type='checkbox' checked={props.item.completed} onChange={() => props.handleChange(props.item.id)} /> 
            <p>{props.item.text}</p>
        </div>
    )
}

export default TodoItem
```

And here's *todosData.js**

```
const todosData = [
    {
        id: 1,
        text: "Take out the trash",
        completed: true
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        text: "Grocery shopping",
        completed: false
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        text: "Clean gecko tank",
        completed: false
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        text: "Mow Lawn",
        completed: true
    },
    {
        id: 5, 
        text: "Catch up on arrested development",
        completed: false
    }
]

export default todosData
```

I've tried using a callback but it isn't working. I've checked prevState and the updated state, but no change is reflected.

I'd appreciate your help on this.

Comment: What errors are you seeing? Can you add error logs to the question?

Comment: You should add `todosData` and please clearly specify what should be the expected result and what problem you are facing?

Comment: Also, what does `console.log("Changed", id)` give you?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @justarandomguy - there are no error logs. The checkbox simply isn't changing. The id parameter is properly passed but state seems fixed

Comment: @JoelPeltonen `console.log("Changed", id)` gives me the id of the element I click on. No problems there

Comment: @decpk: the expected result is that when the checkbox is clicked, the it toggles the `props.item.completed` and this in turn should flip between checked and unchecked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are updating the `state` using `setState`, You should return new `object` to tell react that this is the change and React will update it accordingly.

**Live Demo**

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

React will compare the reference of two objects and if you won't return new object then react will take as a same object. React won't figure out when you won't return new object. You are just updating a property of an object as :

```
if (todo.id === id) {
   todo.completed = !todo.completed
}
```

You just have to make a small change as:

```
if (todo.id === id) {
   return { ...todo, completed: !todo.completed };
}
```

Comment: This totally works. I'm not sure why it behaves differently when other people use it though.

Many thanks @decpk

Answer (score 0):

Being super curious, I tried your code and it works perfectly for me. Is this not what you wanted to happen? Check the snippet below:

```js
document.onreadystatechange = () => {
  const { useState, Component } = React;

  class App extends Component {
    constructor() {
      super();

      this.state = {
        todos: todosData,
      };

      this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange(id) {
      this.setState((prevState) => {
        console.log("PrevState Start ", prevState.todos);
        const updatedTodos = prevState.todos.map((todo) => {
          if (todo.id === id) {
            todo.completed = !todo.completed;
          }
          return todo;
        });

        return {
          todos: updatedTodos,
        };
      });

      console.log("Changed", id);
    }

    render() {
      const todoItem = this.state.todos.map((x) => (
        <TodoItem handleChange={this.handleChange} key={x.id} item={x} />
      ));

      return <div>{todoItem}</div>;
    }
  }

  function TodoItem(props) {
    return (
      <div>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          checked={props.item.completed}
          onChange={() => props.handleChange(props.item.id)}
        />
        <p>{props.item.text}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }

  const todosData = [
    {
      id: 1,
      text: "Take out the trash",
      completed: true,
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      text: "Grocery shopping",
      completed: false,
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      text: "Clean gecko tank",
      completed: false,
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      text: "Mow Lawn",
      completed: true,
    },
    {
      id: 5,
      text: "Catch up on arrested development",
      completed: false,
    },
  ];

  ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#root"));
};
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Sure it is.

that's what I can't figure out. How can same give different results? I literally copied and pasted every thing Bob Ziroll typed the exact way he typed it.

Comment: I'm sorry? I don't really understand, your question was "I've tried using a callback but it isn't working. I've checked prevState and the updated state, but no change is reflected." but with the code you provided, the change is reflected - it is working and you are using a callback @KehindeJejelaye

Comment: Perhaps I wasn't clear enough. The code is meant to work...but it isn't. I tried using a callback because I thought something was wrong from my end. But that is not the case. 

I suppose I wanted to know why the change isn't reflected even when the code is correct.

Comment: "The code is meant to work...but it isn't." - but in my example it _is_ clearly working. "why the change isn't reflected even when the code is correct. " - the change _is_ reflected. @KehindeJejelaye